# Elementary differentiation question on derivation of p.d.f. of function of random variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, derivatives

Let $G(y) = \Pr(Y \le y) = 1 - F(\frac{1}{y})$.
Then apply the chain rule (assuming $y \ne 0$ and $F(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 1/y$) and we have $$g(y) = \frac {d\ G(y)}{dy} = \frac{-d\ F(x)}{dx} \Large \mid_{\normalsize x = 1/y} \normalsize \left(-\frac{1}{y^2} \right)  = f\left( \frac{1}{y}\right)\frac{1}{y^2} $$

This is just a really elementary question on differentiation applied to probability density functions which are one-to-one and differentiable. Still, I'm having trouble seeing the steps which lead to even the first equality after $\frac {d\ G(y)}{dy}$. Is there any way to show the steps to the calculation above more explicitly, particularly for those not so skilled at calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the notation $Df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

The basic rules are: If $g=g_1+g_2$, then $Dg = Dg_1+Dg_2$. If $h= a \circ b$, then $D h(x) = Da(b(x)) Db(x)$.

Here $g_1(x) = 1$$, g_2(x) = -F(\frac{1}{y})$.

This gives $Dg_1(x) = 0$.

To compute $Dg_2$, write $g_2=a \circ b$ where $a(x) = -F(x)$, $b(x) = \frac{1}{y}$. Then we have $Da(x) = -F'(x)$, and $Db(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Putting them altogether gives: $Dg(x) = 0 - (F'(\frac{1}{x}) (- \frac{1}{x^2}) = \frac{1}{x^2} F'(\frac{1}{x})$.

Comment: I almost see it, but I am confused on how $Da(x) = F'(x)$. If $a(x)= -F(x)$, I thought that $Da(x)$ would be equal to $\frac{d}{dx}(-F(x)) = -1 \cdot F'(x)$

Comment: Answer is close enough so I'll mark it.

Comment: @FoF: Thanks for catching the typo. Fixed now.

Comment: got it and thanks.